# Why doesn't this split string expression give me an array?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, split

I am wondering why this array expression in Bash doesn't give me an array. It just gives me the first element in the string:

```
IFS='\n' read -r -a POSSIBLE_ENCODINGS <<< $(iconv -l)
```

I want to try out all available encodings to see how reading different file encodings for a script in R works, and I am using this Bash-script to create text-files with all possible encodings:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='\n' read -r -a POSSIBLE_ENCODINGS <<< $(iconv -l)
echo "${POSSIBLE_ENCODINGS[@]}"

for CURRENT_ENCODING in "${POSSIBLE_ENCODINGS[@]}"
do
        TRIMMED=$(echo $CURRENT_ENCODING | sed 's:/*$::')
        iconv --verbose --from-code=UTF-8 --to-code="$TRIMMED" --output=encoded-${TRIMMED}.txt first_file.txt
        echo "Current encoding: ${TRIMMED}"
        echo "Output file:encoded-${TRIMMED}.txt"
done
```

EDIT: Code edited according to answers below:

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t possibleEncodings <<< "$(iconv -l)"
echo "${possibleEncodings[@]}"

for currentEncoding in "${possibleEncodings[@]}"
do
        trimmedEncoding=$(echo $currentEncoding | sed 's:/*$::')
        echo "Trimmed encoding: ${trimmedEncoding}"
        iconv --verbose --from-code=UTF-8 --to-code="$trimmedEncoding" --output=encoded-${trimmedEncoding}.txt first_file.txt
        echo "Current encoding: ${trimmedEncoding}"
        echo "Output file:encoded-${trimmedEncoding}.txt"
done
```

Comment: `IFS='\n'` says that fields are separate by either a backslash or an "n", not a newline. You could use `IFS=$'\n'` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just `readarray`/`mapfile` instead which are tailor made for reading multi-line output into an array.

```
mapfile -t possibleEncodings < <(iconv -l)
```

The here-strings are useless, when you can just run the command in a process-substitution model. The `<()` puts the command output as if it appears on a file for `mapfile` to read from.

As for *why* your original attempt didn't work, you are just doing the `read` call once, but there is still strings to read in the subsequent lines. You either need to read till EOF in a loop or use the `mapfile` as above which does the job for you.

As a side-note always use lowercase letters for user defined variable/array and function names. This lets you distinguish your variables from the shell's own environment variables which are upper-cased.

Answer (score 1):

because `read` reads only one line, following while can be used

```
arr=()
while read -r line; do
    arr+=( "$line" )
done <<< "$(iconv -l)"
```

otherwise, there is also `readarray` builtin

```
readarray -t arr <<< "$(iconv -l)"
```

Comment: For info: strace gives me execution times (sec.) of 0.000119 for readarray, 0.000145 for mapfile, and 0.000154 for the loop